# Move comments to chat?

Tags: discussion

This question:
[Professorship without PhD in the United States](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/professorship-without-phd-in-the-united-states) has a number of comments about what would happen if a person without a PhD proved the Riemann hypothesis. I think the comments are probably better in chat and might make an interesting chat discussion.

I flagged one of them, but wanted to pitch the idea here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you in theory, but unfortunately SE chat is used by only a fraction of users. That said, I'll post a notice there suggesting further discussion take place in chat.